# Reading body of http.Request without modifying request state?

Tags: http, io, go

I have a type implementing the `http.Handler` interface where, in its `ServeHTTP` method, incoming HTTP requests are inspected, some action is taken, and then the requests are forwarded to a reverse proxy handler (`httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy`).

This works fine, so long as I'm only inspecting the basic request properties, such as the URL or headers.

When I want to inspect the body of an incoming POST request, e.g. by calling `req.ParseForm()` and then using the `req.Form` property, I run into an error once the request is passed onto the reverse proxy:

> `http: proxy error: http: Request.ContentLength=687 with Body length 0`

I imagine this happens because looking at the body of the HTTP request causes the `req.Body.Reader` stream to be drained, meaning it cannot be read again by the proxy handler.

I've been playing with things like `io.Copy()` and `bufio.Peek()`, but I'm not really getting anywhere.

Is there a way to peek at the HTTP request body (and use the built-in parsing of `req.ParseForm` etc.), while leaving the original request object in its original state, so that it can be passed to the reverse proxy?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `Body` with a seekable reader like `bytes.Reader`? You can set `Body` to every value that implements `ReadCloser`.

Comment: Untested (but worth a try): Make a deep copy of the Request as needed, i.e. all but not Body and .*Form. Then use io.TeeReader to clone Request.Body, wrap it in an NopCloser and stuff into the deepcopy of the request. Pass the deep copy to the reverse proxy.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Try reading into a buffer and then using the buffer to back two new readers, one for you to use, and one for subsequent consumers to use. For example, imagine that we want to modify the following code:

```
doStuff(r.Body) // r is an http.Request
```

We could do:

```
buf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
rdr1 := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(buf))
rdr2 := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(buf))

doStuff(rdr1)
r.Body = rdr2 // OK since rdr2 implements the io.ReadCloser interface

// Now the program can continue oblivious to the fact that
// r.Body was ever touched.
```

Note that `*bytes.Buffer` does not have a `Close() error` method, so it doesn't implement the `io.ReadCloser` interface. Thus, we have to wrap our `*bytes.Buffer` values in calls to `ioutil.NopCloser`.

Comment: Yep, np! And good catch on the Close signature. I guess reading the documentation is important after all ;)

Comment: You can get a `io.ReadCloser` from a buffer using the `io.NopCloser` function, e.g. `io.NopCloser(buf)`. See http://golang.org/src/pkg/io/ioutil/ioutil.go?s=3623:3664#L111

Comment: perhaps a TeeReader would be usefull

Comment: This works nicely, but only for bounded bodies that you can hold in memory or on disk.

Comment: @Joppe, that's a good point. You'd need something much more subtle and complicated if you wanted to gracefully handle unbounded or too-large-for-memory requests.

Comment: `drainBody` in https://golang.org/src/net/http/httputil/dump.go#L26 offers a similar solution, but taking `http.NoBody` into account.

Answer (score -2):

I used a different approach to this more recently. There is a `GetBody` method available, through which you can get a new copy of the request body, so instead of doing:

```
doStuff(r.Body)
```

You could instead do:

```
body, _ := r.GetBody()
doStuff(body)
// r.Body is unmodified
```

This allows you to inspect the request body while still having it around to do further processing later

Comment: `GetBody()` is only used for client requests. For server requests it is unused.