# Sending post request from middleware

Tags: go

I want to make middleware func to check token's validity, but at the end function I cannot get post value of it's request.

Here I put "brief" (code just to show the main idea)

```
func main() {
  http.Handle("/100000/000001", Verify(http.HandlerFunc(Insert)))
}

func Verify(next http.Handler) http.Handler
{
   return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      var reqBody RequestBody
      decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
      err := decoder.Decode(&reqBody)
      Util.CheckErr(err)
      var token = RequestHeader{Token: r.Header.Get("_Token")}

      if token == dbToken {
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
      } else {
        Util.PutResponseMessage(w, "003", "Access danied")
      }

   })
}

func Insert(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
  var requestBody InsertRequestBody
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    err := decoder.Decode(&requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer req.Body.Close()

    log.Println(requestBody.Username)
}
```

I get error like this :

```
http: panic serving [::1]:51269: EOF
goroutine 6 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc0420348c0)
    C:/Go/src/net/http/server.go:1721 +0xd7
panic(0x6884e0, 0xc042008110)
```

But, If I directly return next.ServeHttp(r, w)

like this :

```
func Verify(next http.Handler) http.Handler
{
      next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Then decoding process in Insert func working perfectly.

Why is it? Any answer will highly appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: In verify you're seemingly unnecessarily reading the body of the request, by decoding it, and not using the result. Reading the body in Verify the io.Reader is, I assume, at EOF when you try to read it again in Insert... If you don't need the body data in verify, then just remove the decoding from there and you should be ok to go.

Comment: as I've already explain above, I do not include the full code, just some point to letting know the main idea. v

Comment: Ok but the cause of the error still stands, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070876/reading-body-of-http-request-without-modifying-request-state) on how to solve it.

Comment: Basically you have to do a little bit of extra work to be able to read the request body more than once.

Comment: so technically decoding a request is changing it's state?

Comment: Yup, the body is an `io.ReadCloser` and the `json.Decoder` is calling the readcloser's `Read` method until **EOF**, and when you try to decode the body a second time, the readcloser's position is still at the end and so you get **EOF** right off the bat, hence the panic `http: panic serving [::1]:51269: EOF`

Comment: Thanks dude, you save my Day!

Comment: I'm glad I could help