# Logging All HTTP Request and Response from done through an HTTP Client

Tags: http, go, logging

I have the following simple `http.Client`:

```golang
import (
 "net/http"
 "log"
)
...
func main() {
   ...
   link = "http://example.com"
   method = "GET"
   req, _ := http.NewRequest(method, link, nil)

   client := &http.Client{}

   myZapLogger.Info("Sending a %s request to %s\n", method, link)

   resp, err := client.Do(req)
   if err != nil {
      myZapLogger.Error(..., err) // I'm logging rather than fatal-ing or so
   } else { 
      myZapLogger.Info("Received a %d on request X", resp.StatusCode)
   }
   ...
}

...
```

I was looking for a way to do the above for each request through a hook (or so), so that it's triggered automatically each time. I can write a function the encloses all that, but in a case where I'm passing an http client to some other package, I wouldn't be able to control/log such requests that way (e.g. `aws-go-sdk`).

Is there a way to do this through contexts or attaching hooks to the client?

Thanks

Comment: Retouch http.RoundTripper interace in http.Client.Transport.

Comment: Yup. I just realized that it's doable that way; feel free to put an answer if you feel like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**eudore**'s comment answers the question; I'll just put it into code:

```golang
type MyRoundTripper struct {}

func (t MyRoundTripper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    
    // Do work before the request is sent

    resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }
    
    // Do work after the response is received

    return resp, err
}
```

To use it, you'll just pass it to your HTTP Client:

```golang
rt := MyRoundTripper{}
client := http.Client{Transport: rt}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've remixed a few different places and came up with this code:

```
package matrix

import (
    "bytes"
    "mylogger/colorlogger"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

func filterAuthorization(headers http.Header) http.Header {
    filteredHeaders := make(http.Header)
    for k, v := range headers {
        if k == "Authorization" {
            filteredHeaders[k] = []string{"<removed>"}
        } else {
            filteredHeaders[k] = v
        }
    }
    return filteredHeaders
}
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070876/reading-body-of-http-request-without-modifying-request-state
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69276445/logging-all-http-request-and-response-from-done-through-an-http-client
type MyRoundTripper struct{}

func (t MyRoundTripper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    var reqStr string
    var respStr string

    if req.Body != nil {
        reqbuf, e := io.ReadAll(req.Body)
        if e != nil {
            colorlogger.Log.Fatal("Reading http response from RoundTrip injector error: ", e)
        } else {
            reqrdr1 := io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(reqbuf))
            reqrdr2 := io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(reqbuf))
            req.Body = reqrdr2
            // read resp.Body to string
            breq, errreq := io.ReadAll(reqrdr1)
            if errreq != nil {
                colorlogger.Log.Error("Reading http request from RoundTrip injector error: ", errreq)
            } else {
                reqStr = string(breq)
            }
        }
    }

    // Do work before the request is sent
    resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
    if err != nil {
        return resp, err
    }

    if resp.Body != nil {
        respbuf, e := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if e != nil {
            colorlogger.Log.Fatal("Reading http response from RoundTrip injector error: ", e)
        } else {
            resprdr2 := io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(respbuf))
            resp.Body = resprdr2
            resprdr1 := io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(respbuf))
            // read resp.Body to string
            b, errresp := io.ReadAll(resprdr1)
            if errresp != nil {
                colorlogger.Log.Error("Reading http response from RoundTrip injector error: ", errresp)
            } else {
                respStr = string(b)
            }
        }
    }

    // Do work after the response is received
    colorlogger.Log.Debugf("%sREQUEST(%s) %s, Headers: %+v, Body: %s, RESPONSE(%d), Headers: %+v, Body: %s%s",
        colorlogger.Blue,
        req.Method,
        req.URL.Path,
        filterAuthorization(req.Header),
        reqStr,
        resp.StatusCode,
        resp.Header,
        respStr,
        colorlogger.CLR)

    return resp, err
}
```

And as show below, this is integrated like this:

> To use it, you'll just pass it to your HTTP Client:
>
> rt := MyRoundTripper{} client := http.Client{Transport: rt}

**Note:** I might change error handling a bit because of the **fatal**.

**Note:** I also liked https://medium.com/@motemen/add-a-single-line-to-your-go-source-and-track-every-http-requests-responses-37f2f15eb72f but I'd like to be able to change from debug to none-debug during runtime later.